# Replace two letter state code with full name in string - Python 3.8.x

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of ~60K strings, all looking like this:

`strings = ['corpus christi tx', 'san angelo', 'oklahoma city ok', 'abilenesweetwater']`

I also have a `dict` of lookups. For an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

`lookup = {'tx': 'texas', 'ny': 'new york', 'nj': 'new jersey', 'ok': 'oklahoma'}`

What I would like to do, is loop through my list of strings, and replace the two-digit state code with the `value` in the dictionary, making the resulting list look like:

`new_strings = ['corpus christi texas', 'san angelo', 'oklahoma city oklahoma', 'abilenesweetwater']`

I have seen many similar questions that are looking to do this where the two-digit state code (or full state name) is a column of a `pd.Dataframe`, but not as an independent string. I am assuming I will need a `regex`.

I have tried the following:

```
print("Test", 'corpus christi tx')
new_test_str = re.sub(r'[\s+tx+\s]', 'texas', 'corpus christi tx')
print("Reply", new_test_str)
```

Which (incorrectly) yields:

```
Test corpus christi tx
Reply corpustexaschristexasitexastexastexas
```

Comment: your regex is wrong ...`[...]` syntax is a character class, so `[\s+tx+\s]` will match every `\s` (space, tab etc) char, every `+` char, every `t` and `x` chars and replace them with the target string

Comment: I don't doubt that, but then the question may be answered by a correct `re` that populates the requested results

Comment: to replace `tx` with `texas` you can try `re.sub(r'\btx\b', 'texas', 'corpus christi tx')` ... `\b` matches a "word boundary" without actually including the space char in the replacement match itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regex from the dictionary keys to match them as whole words, and get values from the dictionary once the match is found and replace with that value:

```py
import re
strings = ['corpus christi tx', 'san angelo', 'oklahoma city ok', 'abilenesweetwater']
lookup = {'tx': 'texas', 'ny': 'new york', 'nj': 'new jersey', 'ok': 'oklahoma'}
rx =  re.compile(fr'\b(?:{"|".join([key for key in lookup])})\b')
strings = [rx.sub(lambda x: lookup[x.group()], s) for s in strings]
```

Output:

```
>>> strings
['corpus christi texas', 'san angelo', 'oklahoma city oklahoma', 'abilenesweetwater']
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/oe4raq).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to replace the strings. Assuming that the state code is always in the end of the string, you write a regex pattern to find such strings, and replace it with the value in your lookup dictionary.

```
import re    
strings = ['corpus christi tx', 'san angelo', 'oklahoma city ok', 'abilenesweetwater']
lookup = {'tx': 'texas', 'ny': 'new york', 'nj': 'new jersey', 'ok': 'oklahoma'}
_patt = re.compile(r'\s(\w{2})$')

strings = [re.sub(_patt.search(s).group(1), lookup.get(_patt.search(s).group(1)), s) if _patt.search(s) else s for s in strings]
```

Output:

```
['corpus christi texas', 'san angelo', 'oklahomalahoma city oklahoma', 'abilenesweetwater']
```

To understand this code in detail, here is the easier implementation of the same code:

```
for each in strings:
    match = _patt.search(each)
    if match:
        each = re.sub(match.group(1), lookup.get(match.group(1)), each)
        print(each)
```